# How do I build a custom table to display message trace results in Poweshell?

Tags: powershell

I need to report on several shared mailboxes sent and received emails over a week. The goal is to have 2 tables, one which shows each mailbox and a count of their received emails broken out by days, the other table shows the same but for sent emails. Ideally would look something like the below:

| Mailbox | Received Monday | Received Tuesday | Received Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email@domain.com | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| email2@domain.com | 987 | 654 | 321 |

I'm able to get the count of sent and received emails for each of the mailboxes but I haven't been able to format these results into a table. I've tried using Format-Table to do this but it doesn't print any results.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
Param(

    [DateTime] $start = '2021-12-07 00:00:00',
    [DateTime] $end = '2021-12-07 23:59:59',
    $emailSent1,
    $emailReceived1,
    $emailSent2,
    $emailReceived2

)

function Get-Emails {


    $emailSent1 = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress mailbox@domain.com -StartDate $start -EndDate $end
    $emailReceived1 = Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress mailbox@domain.com -StartDate $start -EndDate $end
    $emailSent2 = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress mailbox2@domain.com -StartDate $start -EndDate $end
    $emailReceived2 = Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress mailbox2@domain.com -StartDate $start -EndDate $end

    
}


Get-Emails | Format-Table SenderAddress,$emailSent1.Count.ToString()
```

Comment: The `Get-Emails` function never outputs anything - it just assigns the results of the `Get-MessageTrace` calls to four local variables, nothing else. Remove the `$emailSent1 = ` part, repeat for all four

Comment: If I do this I also get nothing. I can add .Count to the end of those variables which gives me the result but I can't format the results of that into a table

Comment: Whilst not related to your question, I thought it would be best to mention that using message trace on a senders address could give an excessive / inflated count of actual emails sent. Reason for this is because a singe email with multiple recipients will have a message trace entry for each of the recipients, for accuracy I would advise grouping by the `MessageId` property as this is unique to an individual email and will be the same for each of the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution but you can inspire to group mails sent by
`DayOfWeek`. The recipient or sender property should be kept as well in the group. Then you need to convert `DayOfWeek` as a property and the `Count` as a value. You can also add others properties like recipient or sender and this should give the desired result.
You should process one sender or recipient at a time, for sending or receiving.

```
$objs = @(
    $( New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{name  = "test1"; date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(1)} ),
    $( New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{name  = "test1"; date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(2)} )
)

$groups = $objs | Select-Object -Property *, @{l = 'Day'; e= { $_.date.DayOfWeek }} | Group-Object Day -NoElement
$properties = @{}
foreach($group in $groups) {
    $properties.Add($group.Name, $group.Count)
}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
```